# Android: Registring to server Nullpointer exception at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal

Tags: android, sql, android-asynctask, phpmyadmin

I did this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArJDXM-HHqk&spfreload=10

and also copied this working code from other student: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e0bfcd7a9e954ae574d59c123cb0c4ae

And still I get this error again and again:

```
01-01 23:24:00.727 2759-2759/com.example.loginapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
    at com.example.loginapp.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:52)
    at com.example.loginapp.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:26)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5413)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I had a typo in the method name, "Register" instead of "register".
now it works fine.